# Converting Lubridate Period Class Time to Time Stamp Format in R

Tags: r, time, format

My code reads in a .txt file that holds a series of time stamps in one column. I needed to account for daylight savings for the column, so I used the lubridate package to subtract an hour from these time stamps. I'm struggling with converting the period class from lubridate back into a time format of %I:%M%:S %p.

Here is my code.

```
  # Changing from 24 Hr to 12 Hr Format #
  raw_data_sample$Time <- format(strptime(raw_data_sample$Time, format='%H:%M:%S'), '%I:%M:%S %p')
  
  # Subtracting an Hour for Daylight Savings
  raw_data_sample$Time <- hms(raw_data_sample$Time)
  raw_data_sample$Time <- raw_data_sample$Time - hours(1)
```

Here is my current output.

```
c("1H 41M 54S", "1H 42M 4S", "1H 42M 14S", "1H 42M 31S", "1H 42M 41S", "1H 43M 1S")
```

I'm hoping to get an output like

```
1:41:54 PM, 1:42:40 PM
```

Any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to subtract an hour, do this on the original datetime object, and then do the `format`ting

```
library(lubridate)
# // convert to Datetime class 
raw_data_sample$Time <- as.POSIXct(raw_data_sample$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
 # // subtract 1 hour from the Datetime and use format to change the format
format(raw_data_sample$Time %m-% hours(1), "%I:%M:%S %p")
```

Comment: thank you for your response! I should have clarified, my original time format for the dataframe is just HH:MM:SS, no date. When I write your suggestion, I get "Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format" which I'm assuming is due to the lack of the date being in the format.

Comment: @user14880462 just specify the `format` in `as.POSIXct` i.e. `format  = "%H:%M:%S"`

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parse_date_time` function to convert your period object to POSIXct then use `format` to get in your suitable format.

```
library(lubridate)
raw_data_sample$Time1 <- format(parse_date_time(raw_data_sample$Time, 'HMS'), '%I:%M:%S %p')
```

For example,

```
x <- period(c("1H 41M 54S", "1H 42M 4S", "1H 42M 14S", "1H 42M 31S", "1H 42M 41S", "1H 43M 1S"))
format(parse_date_time(x, 'HMS'), '%I:%M:%S %p')
#[1] "01:41:54 AM" "01:42:04 AM" "01:42:14 AM" "01:42:31 AM" "01:42:41 AM" "01:43:01 AM"
```